# Postgresql: A bit confused on listing all roles in my system

Tags: postgresql

I am just getting into PostgreSQL. I am ultimately interested in using PostGIS but thought it would pay off in the long run to get thoroughly familiar with the client/server authentication systems and also some general database management concepts through the command line instead of pgadmin GUI.

Going through the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/database-roles.html), it shows two methods for listing the defomed roles in the system.

```
\du
```

and

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles
```

I wanted to try these out on my own system, and I did the following in `cmd`:

```
psql -U postgres
psql (11.1)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Then I did:

```
postgres=# SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles;
          rolname
---------------------------
 pg_monitor
 pg_read_all_settings
 pg_read_all_stats
 pg_stat_scan_tables
 pg_read_server_files
 pg_write_server_files
 pg_execute_server_program
 pg_signal_backend
 postgres
(9 rows)
```

As you can see the listed roles are different, which is very confusing to me. my `pg_hba.conf` file is as follows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I changed all the authentication methods to `trust` because I wanted to facilitate access to the superuser role, since I forgot my password and could not find any straightforward method to retrieve it.

Why are the role names different for the two commands? Are

```
 pg_monitor
 pg_read_all_settings
 pg_read_all_stats
 pg_stat_scan_tables
 pg_read_server_files
 pg_write_server_files
 pg_execute_server_program
 pg_signal_backend
```

also roles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find out, what exactly the "backslash commands" do, just start `psql` with the option `-E` (or `--echo-hidden`).

If you do that, you will see that `\du` uses the following query:

```
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
ORDER BY 1;
```

So `\du` simply filters out all roles where the name starts with `pg_`, because role names starting with `pg_` are reserved for Postgres built-in roles and you can't create a role with that prefix manually.

The default roles are [explained in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/default-roles.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing are `Default Roles` as you can see in [`Documentation Default Roles`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/default-roles.html).

And from [`Documentation Database Roles`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/user-manag.html)

> PostgreSQL manages database access permissions using the concept of
>   roles. A role can be thought of as either a database user, or a group
>   of database users, depending on how the role is set up.

And @a_horse_with_no_name give the more specific the behind `\du`